# How can I get the complete predecessors list based on a direct predecessor list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My problem is related to the extraction of ore blocks in an open pit mine. Where the blocks have a relation of pecedência, as explained below.
In this representation we have 6 blocks, where:
[image: Mine example for 9 blocks.]

In this case we can only "extract" block 6 if 1, 2 and 3 have already been extracted, block 7 if 2,3,4 have been extracted, block 8 if 3, 4, 5 have already been extracted and the block 9 if 6,7,8 have already been extracted.

```py
import sys
blocks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]#list of blocks
p = [[] for i in blocks]#list of direct precedents
p[0] = []
p[1] = []
p[2] = []
p[3] = []
p[4] = []
p[5] = [1,2,3]
p[6] = [2,3,4]
p[7] = [3,4,5]
p[8] = [6,7,8]
```

From this direct list of precedents, I'd like a method that would help get the following "complete list of precedents" for instances larger than 9 blocks (something between 1060 and 100000 blocks).

```py
import sys
blocks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]#list of blocks
p = [[] for i in blocks]#full list of precedents
p[0] = []
p[1] = []
p[2] = []
p[3] = []
p[4] = []
p[5] = [1,2,3]
p[6] = [2,3,4]
p[7] = [3,4,5]
p[8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed to always have a "filled" triangle? If not, how does the input array relate to the partially filled triangle? Maybe try building a tree-like structure, but with more than one parent for each child?

Comment: So the problem is not computing the initial list of precedents, right? That would be an input in this case?

Comment: Yes, I already have the initial precedents list.

Comment: Patrik, 
this is the problem. Theoretically it should be triangulate the precedence relation, but in practice it is not.
But the jdehesa method worked perfectly for any type of block arrangement. Many thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it iterating the blocks in [topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Here is one possible way to do it:

```
def precedents_transitive(blocks, precedents):
    num_blocks = len(precedents)
    # Mapping between block ids and indices
    mapping = {b: i for i, b in enumerate(blocks)}
    # Direct precedents as sets
    ps = list(map(set, precedents))
    # Transitive precedents as sets, starts with direct precedents
    ps_transitive = list(map(set, precedents))
    # Remaining blocks to visit
    remaining = set(blocks)
    # Visited blocks
    visited = set()
    while remaining:
        # Find a non-visited block such that all its precedents have been visited
        for block in remaining:
            i_block = mapping[block]
            if ps[i_block] <= visited:
                break
        else:
            # If we get here the input was not valid
            raise ValueError('Invalid precedents.')
        # Add transitive precedents of direct predecessors
        ps_transitive[i_block].update(*(ps_transitive[mapping[pred]] for pred in ps[i_block]))
        remaining.remove(block)
        visited.add(block)
    return list(map(sorted, ps_transitive))
```

Here is a test with your data:

```
# List of blocks
blocks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# List of direct precedents
p = [[] for i in blocks]
p[0] = []
p[1] = []
p[2] = []
p[3] = []
p[4] = []
p[5] = [1, 2, 3]
p[6] = [2, 3, 4]
p[7] = [3, 4, 5]
p[8] = [6, 7, 8]
p_transitive = precedents_transitive(blocks, p)
print(p_transitive)
```

Output:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's build a more interesting example:

```
pit = """
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
   12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
      21 22 23 24 25 26 27
         28 29 30 31 32
            33 34 35
               36
"""

direct_predecessors = {}
row_below = []
for line in pit.strip().split( '\n' )[ ::-1 ]:
    row_current = [ int( x ) for x in line.split() ]
    for i, item in enumerate( row_below ):
        direct_predecessors[ item ] = row_current[ i : i + 3 ]
    row_below = row_current
```

(NB: unlike your question, where the predecessor-lookup keys are zero-based but the values are one-based, I've chosen to use a dictionary where the value entries can be used directly as keys. In fact, if I hadn't converted them explicitly to `int()`, the block labels could be arbitrary strings.  If we print the content:

```
for key, value in sorted( direct_predecessors.items() ):
    print( '%r : %r' % ( key, value ) )
```

then we get the following output:

```
12 : [1, 2, 3]
13 : [2, 3, 4]
14 : [3, 4, 5]
15 : [4, 5, 6]
16 : [5, 6, 7]
17 : [6, 7, 8]
18 : [7, 8, 9]
19 : [8, 9, 10]
20 : [9, 10, 11]
21 : [12, 13, 14]
22 : [13, 14, 15]
23 : [14, 15, 16]
24 : [15, 16, 17]
25 : [16, 17, 18]
26 : [17, 18, 19]
27 : [18, 19, 20]
28 : [21, 22, 23]
29 : [22, 23, 24]
30 : [23, 24, 25]
31 : [24, 25, 26]
32 : [25, 26, 27]
33 : [28, 29, 30]
34 : [29, 30, 31]
35 : [30, 31, 32]
36 : [33, 34, 35]
```

OK, now to answer your question: given the direct predecessors, get all the (direct and indirect) predecessors.  A recursive approach is one way to go:

```
def Predecessors( n ):
    result = set( direct_predecessors.get( n, [] ) )
    result |= { indirect for direct in result for indirect in Predecessors( direct ) }
    return result
```

If we try an example:

```
print( Predecessors( 31 ) )
```

the output is as follows:

```
set([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26])
```